# Context-free language as regular expression

Tags: context-free-grammar, regular-expressions

I want to ask a short question. Can a regular expression expresses a context-free language that is not a regular language?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Context-free languages can be more complex then what regular expressions can represent. Every regular language can be expressed as a regular expression; and every regular expression accepts a regular language.